# How to add unique mobile number by using Cakephp 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I know for email address, which is given below. so, suggest me for mobile number.

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
         $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        return $rules;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replicate what you've got for checking the `email` address is unique for the relevant mobile field. For example, if your field was `phone`:-

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['phone']));
    return $rules;
}
```

You can read more on validating unique fields in the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules).

Comment: It is very useful. Thank you

Comment: @a.shah if it helped solve your problem please accept it as the answer. 

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this : 
1.

```
$validator
    ->notEmpty('phone',__('Please enter phone.',true))
    ->add('phone',[
        'phoneUniqueCheck'=>[
            'rule'      =>  'phoneUniqueCheck',
            'provider'  =>  'table',
            'message'   =>  'phone id already exists.'
         ]
    ]);

   public function emailUniqueCheck($value,$context){
        $phone           =  $context['data']['phone'];  
        $data    =  $this->find('all')->where(array('phone' => $phone))->first();   

        if(empty($data)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

2.

```
$validator->requirePresence('phone',true,__('Please enter phone'))  
    ->add('phone', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table','message' => 'Phone id already exists.']);
```

Comment: why you downvote my answer, if my answer is correct then plz accept